# data-target not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement the bootstrap modal, when I click on the add Icon.

But by default `data-target="#undefined"` is getting set.Only after clicking, data-target is getting changed to `data-target="#myModal"`.

I want to set myModal to data-target by default and based on the condition I want to change `data-target` to `myModal` or `alertModal`.

[Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW1pp.png)

I'm stuck here. Please help

```js
public checkUnassigned() {
  let eArray = this.pListComponent.evtNumber;
  if (eArray.length > 0) {
    this.modalName = "alertModal";
  } else {
    this.modalName = "myModal";
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="icon-links"><i *ngIf="(selectedStatus == '01')" class="npt-icon-add icon-states" aria-hidden="true" 
                data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="'#' + modalName"  (click)="checkUnassigned()"></i></a>
```

Comment: this is Angular 2

Comment: That is Typescript

Comment: Try [attr.data-target="{{'#' + modalName}}" or use two <a *ngIf="modalName=='alertModal'" ...><a *ngIf="modalName=='myModal'" ...>

Comment: not working getting error like Can't bind to '[attr.data-target' since it isn't a known property of 'i'. ("== '01')" class="npt-icon-add icon-states" aria-hidden="true" 
                data-toggle="modal" [ERROR ->][attr.data-target="{{'#' + modalName}}"  (click)="checkUnassigned()"></i></a>

Comment: I forgget a "]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the following way. Yet you have to check the `pListComponent.evtNumber` value constantly. I cannot do that part(by the lack of your total code) but suggest you to use '`ngDoCheck`' ([explanation](https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck)) in a way that whenever `pListComponent.evtNumber` is changed, it has to trigger the `checkUnassigned()` function.

Goodluck!

```
isAlertModal:boolean = false;
public checkUnassigned() {
  let eArray = this.pListComponent.evtNumber;
  if (eArray.length > 0) {
    this.isAlertModal = true;
  } else {
    this.isAlertModal = false;
  }
}


<a class="icon-links">
    <i *ngIf="((selectedStatus == '01') && (isAlertModal==false))" class="npt-icon-add icon-states" aria-hidden="true" 
        data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="#myModal"  (click)="checkUnassigned()"></i>

    <i *ngIf="((selectedStatus == '01') && (isAlertModal==true))" class="npt-icon-add icon-states" aria-hidden="true" 
        data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="#alertModal"  (click)="checkUnassigned()"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: i got an error like this [ts] '=' expected.
[ts] Cannot find name 'checkUnassigned'.
any

Comment: You can declare a variable in the class and store the result in it then make a check. I will edit the code now

Comment: got an error - Unexpected token # at column 1 in [#myModal]

Comment: Were you able to open the modal even before? Because I open it in this way-> (click)="myModal.openModal()" so you have to arrange the code accordingly. I have showed you the way how to give a default value and show the 'i' tag accordingly. The rest is kind of up to you.

Comment: You're code is working, but the problem is this line is not getting added [attr.data-target]="myModal"

Comment: try it without the #, I dont know

Comment: I fixed, i've removed the [attr.data-target] to just data-target="#modal" and it worked